# В чем разница между a::hover и a:hover?

Tags: css, css3

Вопрос по псевдо классам. Допустим, есть у меня есть такие ссылки:

```css
a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.link1, .link2 {
transition: all .3s;
}

.link1:hover{
color: #ff9900;
}

.link2::hover{
color: #66ff00;
}
```

```html
<a class = "link1">Ссылка с классом 1</a>
<a class = "link2">Ссылка с классом 2</a>
```

У меня в `google chrome` корректно работает и тот и тот вариант. В здешней консоли почему-то работает только с одним двоеточием, в разных обучающих роликах псевдоклассы пишут то так, то так. В чем разница между `тэг::псевдокласс` и `тэг:псевдокласс`? Правильно писать одно двоеточие или два? Или эти записи вообще обозначают что-то разное?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Изначально всегда использовали `:` до версии CSS3, где начали разделять:

- `:` используется для псевдо-классов (`:hover, :active...`)
- `::` используется для псевдо-элементов (`::before, ::after...`)

Если мы будем писать везде с `:` (к примеру с псевдо-элементом `:before`) и когда-то будет реализован псевдо-класс `:before` (что-либо не значащий), то может случиться что-то непредвиденное *(что навряд случится)*.

Поэтому можете всегда писать с `:`, а можете разделять, и для псевдо-классов писать `:` - и наоборот `::`, для псевдо-элементов, чтобы показать, что Вы крутой.

P.S. Использование `::` в старых браузерах может что-то сломать.